# Convert/wrap static Objective-C framework into a dynamic framework that can be used in a Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dynamic, frameworks

What steps should I follow to convert/wrap a static `Objective-C` framework into a `dynamic framework` that can be used in a `Swift` project?

I have tried the second method described here: https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/convert_static_to_dynamic.html but received errors like below:

> include of non-modular header inside framework module

Answer (score 0):

Behind the scenes, Clang is trying to create a module.map file for the framework. The module.map is what organizes imports when you do something like `@import Foundation`.

Module imports are much more like Java imports than C header includes. The C header include (or old-school Objective-C import) replaces the `#include <whatever.h>` with the content of that file when compiling. A module import is a semantic import of sorts, telling the compiler where symbols are defined and such.

Now, the error *"include of non-modular header inside framework module"* basically means that you have a module (i.e. your new framework) that has a header (any public .h file), that itself has `#import` or `#include` statements from files that are not themselves "module-ized".

The most common mistake, and easiest thing to fix, is to move these `#include`'s into the .m file where they are needed, and out of the .h file.

Also, make sure to setup your framework correctly, especially regarding headers. You want all your public headers including in your umbrella header, and you want to make sure the build process is setup correctly to copy public, private, and project headers as appropriate. The easiest way to get an example is simply to make a new, completely clean Framework project, and look to see how it's setup. Take care to read the comments in the auto-generated umbrella header.